# How to deploy netbeans project or .war in linux(Lubuntu)

Tags: linux, tomcat, netbeans

I created the project (web app) in windows using netbeans... I copied the war file and put it in the "webapps" inside apache-tomcat installed in Lubuntu... I read a lot of forums and search about it but i'm confused. The lubuntu is VM so in my windows, I can access 192.168.56.101:8080 but I dont know how to deploy the Wep App in linux...

Please help me.. I really appreciate ur help

Comment: 1. If you can access tomcat why not use the manager to deploy it? 2. How did you copy the war into the VM did you install guest tools? 3. If you have internet connectivity in VM you can use dropbox to get the war there.

Comment: I copied the .war file in the dist folder of the netbeans in windows and put it in the VM via flash drive... Currently, my .war (and the project folder for testing) file is inside webapps of apache-tomcat in lubuntu but I when I access the folder (192.168.56.101:8080/MyProject) it's 404... how can I deploy the war in the lubuntu??

Answer (score 0):

War files should be extracted automatically on tomcat startup, at your app should be accessible according to the mappings your web.xml, eg `192.168.56.101:8080/myApp`. You can find more information regarding how deploys work with tomcat [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html)

Comment: can you give me some example code on linux, im new to linux... example on how to deploy project in tomcat...

Comment: The official Tomcat documentation, which also has a section on the GUI Manager, should provide sufficient info on the deployment process. I'm not sure I understand what type of code are you interested in. Can you please give a more detailed example what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps I have somehow misunderstood your point

Comment: well, I managed to deploy it using the GUI Manager, but when I start my the project.. 
FAIL - Application at context path /Healthlink could not be started

and this is the log
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854946/fail-application-at-context-path-healthlink-could-not-be-started


im feeling hopeless, I have no idea how to deal with that...