# FAIL - Application at context path /Healthlink could not be started

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I want to deploy it with the .war file generated by netbeans in Windows, my project is a web app, and I want to run in in LINUX (LUBUNTU), but I can't start it. I'm using the manager-gui.

Please help me with this error. I'm new in linux.

```
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib

Sep 18, 2013 12:01:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Sep 18, 2013 12:01:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Sep 18, 2013 12:01:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 3021 ms

Sep 18, 2013 12:01:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Sep 18, 2013 12:01:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42

Sep 18, 2013 12:01:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR

INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/Healthlink.war

Sep 18, 2013 12:01:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Sep 18, 2013 12:01:52 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [147] milliseconds.
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Healthlink] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:52 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/Healthlink] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/host-manager
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/examples
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/docs
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/manager
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:01:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7183 ms
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 4193 ms
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/Healthlink.war
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:51 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [10,839] milliseconds.
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Healthlink] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:51 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/Healthlink] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/host-manager
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/examples
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/docs
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/manager
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:03:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 17665 ms
Sep 18, 2013 12:04:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 18, 2013 12:04:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Healthlink] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 18, 2013 12:04:09 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/Healthlink] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5065 ms
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/Healthlink.war
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Healthlink] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:42 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/Healthlink] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/host-manager
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/examples
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/docs
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/manager
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 18, 2013 12:06:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7305 ms
```

Comment: You can try letting more information through as explained here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/tomcat-6-infamous-%E2%80%9Csevere

Answer (score 2):

Here's the most important line of your overzealously long (and repeated) log:

```
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

This basically means that a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) implementation which is registered by either a `@WebListener` annotation on the class or a `<listener>` entry in `web.xml` has thrown an unhandled exception inside the `contextInitialized()` method. This is usually caused by a developer's mistake (a bug) and needs to be fixed. For example, a `NullPointerException`.

If you can't figure the cause by just staring at or unit-testing the code inside `contextInitialized()` method, then you'd need to create a `logging.properties` file in project's `src` folder (there where you have your Java classes; it should at least ultimately end up in `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of the built WAR) with the following contents:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

This will tell Tomcat to log exceptions during starting of listeners (and filters) to the console.

Comment: where can I view the result of the log of logging.properties?

Comment: The console. The same log as you copypasted the piece in the question from.